# How to install theme on Windows CE 5.0

Tags: mobile, windows-ce, look-and-feel

Is there a way to install themes on Windows CE 5. I want it to look similar to Windows Mobile.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there are themes to windows CE5, because windows CE produced to RUN **Enterprise program** not like windows Mobile produce for **personal usage**.